# Once there is a fingerprint on the fingerprint scanner do something

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-fingerprint-api

I am creating an android app using Xamarin. I want putting a fingerprint on the  scanner to be the same as pressing an on screen button, once there is a finger on the fingerprint scanner I want to execute some code. is this possible and if so could you provide some guidance on how to do this?

Comment: if I'm not wrong what you want is that as soon as a finger comes in contact with the fingerprint scanner you want to perform some actions? @Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want putting a fingerprint on the scanner to be the same as pressing an on screen button, once there is a finger on the fingerprint scanner I want to execute some code. is this possible and if so could you provide some guidance on how to do this?

If you want Finger Print Scanner to act like a button, the answer is yes and no.

For Yes part:

You can refer to [FingerPrint Authentication Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial) to create a fingerprint authentication and start it when your app starts. And inside `FingerPrinthandler` when the authentication fails or succeed, you have your callbacks to execute your codes, you can start the authentication process when succeed(because once the authentication succeed, android system won't ask user to auth again.)

For No part:

Most Android system has a limit for FingerPrint Authentication times. So after a few times of execution, system will prevent user from trying authenticate. So it will never act like a normal button.